# How to fix "city field is not accepting value"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, autofill

I am working on extension that auto fills form on the AliExpress shipping information page.

I managed to fill data in all fields except city field. There is an province field that is dependent on country dropdown and city field if province field has dropdown and user select province which has cities available a dropdown appear for cities other wise input appears for city and same is the processes of city.

Now the problem is if city and province both are input then its assign value to province but not to city and if I don't fill value in province using js then its work fine for city.

I tried by dispatching events, appending script in the body and using different event but nothing worked.

Note: There are two hidden fields with same id's as province and city.

```
if (key == "first_name") {
  $("#contactPerson").focus();
  document.execCommand("insertText", false,
    ae_billing_details[key] + ae_billing_details["last_name"]);
}
if (key == "phone") {
  $("#mobileNo").focus();
  document.execCommand("insertText", false, ae_billing_details[key]);
}
if (key == "address_1") {
  $("#address").focus();
  document.execCommand("insertText", false, ae_billing_details[key]);
}
if (key == "address_2") {
  $("#address2").focus();
  document.execCommand("insertText", false, ae_billing_details[key]);
}
if (key == "state") {
  if ($(".addr-select").has("#province")) {
    $("#province").focus();
    document.execCommand("insertText", false, ae_billing_details[key]);
  }
}
if (key == "postcode") {
  $("#zip").focus();
  document.execCommand("insertText", false, ae_billing_details[key]);
//   var evt = document.createEvent("Events");
//   evt.initEvent("keypress", true, true);
//   evt.view = window;
//   evt.altKey = false;
//   evt.ctrlKey = false;
//   evt.shiftKey = false;
//   evt.metaKey = false;
//   evt.keyCode = 0;
//   evt.charCode = "a";
//   .dispatchEvent(evt);
}
if (key == "city") {
  if ($(".addr-select").has("#city")) {
    $("#city").focus();

    document.execCommand("insertText", false, ae_billing_details[key]);


    $("body").append(
      "<script>document.getElementById('city').value = 'My value';</script>"
    );
    //$( "#city" ).text("gggg");
    //$("#city").attr("value","ok");

    //var element = document.getElementById("#city" );
    // element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    // var value = $("#city").val();
    // $("#city").focus().val("").val(value);

    //$("#city").val("Mush");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem identified and solved. The problem was with sequence of keys. Which Was solved by moving the code out of for  loop because for(var key in obj) fetch in key sequence which was causing the problem but setting state at end so focus was going to province and value was not assigning to city field.